# Failed to install unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Every time I try to download unity editor this error pops up.

`Download failed: permission denied, mkdir '/Volumes/Visual Studio for Mac Installer 2'`

I tried deleting unity and downloading it again, but still the same error pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to login from an account with admin rights.